Trigger Python code with "Navigate to next feature" button on QGIS
I am creating a script in the Action feature of QGIS that plots the values of an attributed table in matplotlib when I click on a feature in a layer as shown below.
class ClickTool(QgsMapToolIdentify):
    def __init__(self, canvas) -> None:
        super().__init__(canvas)
        self.canvas = canvas

    def canvasReleaseEvent(self, event) -> None:
        # Convert the click position to map coordinates
        self.toMapCoordinates(event.pos())

        # Identify features at the click position
        identified_features = self.identify(
            event.x(), event.y(), self.TopDownStopAtFirst, self.VectorLayer
        )

        if not identified_features:
            return
            
        ... # matplotlib codes to plot are here ...
        
        
# Set the custom tool as the active map tool
canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
click_tool = ClickTool(canvas)
canvas.setMapTool(click_tool)


def on_layer_changed() -> None:
    # Directly unset the custom map tool when another layer is selected
    canvas.unsetMapTool(click_tool)


# Assuming 'canvas' and 'click_tool' are defined as in your provided code snippet
# Connect the currentLayerChanged signal to the on_layer_changed function
iface.layerTreeView().currentLayerChanged.connect(on_layer_changed)

Is it possible to trigger the graph display action by clicking on the navigate next features button instead of clicking on the layer feature?


The list with the navigation buttons you are interested in is a QgsFeatureListView. It has a currentEditSelectionChanged signal that is triggered whenever the selected feature changes (through the nav buttons or otherwise), which you could set to a slot that updates your popup graph. The problem is, QGIS doesn't seem to expose that list view anywhere in the public API. You could potentially find it somewhere in the application's QWidget hierarchy, but that is easier said than done, unfortunately.
